# Is there a way to check if code is executed in a TransactionScope?

Tags: c#, .net, transactionscope

Is there a way to check if code is executed in a TransactionScope?

Something like:

```
if(TransactionScope.Started|Enabled){...}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**yes** there is way (directly copied from the MSDN documentation of [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)):

> The ambient transaction is the
>   transaction your code executes in. You
>   can obtain a reference to the ambient
>   transaction by calling the static
>   Current property of the Transaction
>   class.

So have a look at Transaction.[Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.current.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You could check the [Transaction.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.current.aspx) property:

```
if(Transaction.Current != null)
{
    // running inside a transaction
}
```